# How to access float output variables from other classes

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I have a `function` which will randomly select a number from 1 through to 5, and then inside that function I have an `if` statement that will assign the numbers output from the function to a variable called `randID` (for sake of randomly selecting a zone in my game).

In another class, I want to check to see if `zoneID` is equal to `randID` (the one I randomly selected earlier) and if so, I want to print a message.

I would do this in one class, however I have multiple objects in my game using this class and I need the main game operator class to decide which of the zones are selected.

Imagine a game of headquarters; that's essentially what I'm trying to figure out. Most of the system is now in place. :)

I thank you in advance for any assistance or guidance you can offer.

**PS**: I'm using C# and Unity3D to create this project.

**Edit**: Code.

```
public static void DecideID() {
    if (gameLeft >= 1f && timeZone_Zone.zoneAlive == false) {
        float random = Random.Range(0f, 5f);
        print (random);
        if(random > 1f && random < 2f) {
            id = 1;
            print (id);
        } 
        else if(random > 2f && random < 3f) {
            id = 2;
            print (id);
        }
        else if(random > 3f && random < 4f) {
            id = 3;
            print (id);
        }
        else if(random > 4f && random < 5f) {
            id = 4;
            print (id);
        }
        else if(random >= 5f) {
            id = 5;
            print (id);
    }
}
```

The `print (id)` statements are for test purposes only.

Then I want to do something like this:

```
if (zoneID = randID) {
    GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to access the component's variables in another script. Make `randID` public, and then you can access it in another script.

```
TypeWithRand randtype;

...

void Start()
{
    randtype = objWithRand.GetComponent<TypeWithRand>();
}

...

if (randtype.randID == zoneID)
{
    ...
}
```

You will have to replace `TypeWithRand` with the type that contains the methods for the `randID`.

Another way to do this would be to have an instance of the class containing `randID`. Then you could check the value like:

```
RandClass randClass;

...

if (randClass.randID == zoneID)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

This implies that you call `DecideID` (the way I have fixed below) in the constructor of `RandClass`. You could also keep the function as a void, but then set the value of `randID` in your function similar to how you set `id`. Then you would call the function from the instance of the class

```
randClass.DecideID();

if (randClass.randID == zoneID)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Also, your `DecideID` function incorrect in a few ways. First, `Random.Range()` can use ints, without the need for the multiple if statements.

```
id = Random.Range(0, 5);
```

Also you can return the value of id, and reference it later, so `randID`'s assignment would look like

```
randID = DecideID();
```

So, your actual function would look like:

```
public int DecideID() {
    id = 0;
    if (gameLeft >= 1f && timeZone_Zone.zoneAlive == false) {
        id = Random.Range(0, 5);
    }
    return id;
}
```

or

```
public void DecideID() {
    if (gameLeft >= 1f && timeZone_Zone.zoneAlive == false) {
        randID = Random.Range(0, 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've copied a small extract from my script. How would I implement this ? Does another c# file count as a GameObject?

Comment: @JackMiller The gameobject is the object in the scene that you have the script attached to... The type you would substitute would be the type of the script attached to the other gameobject

Comment: So if I wanted to get the value of the float 'id' and then use it in my zone class, how would I do that? 

Something like 

`Handler = GameObject.Find("GameHandler");
Handler.GetComponent<float>(id);

Comment: @Jack No, you would `float rand = Handler.GetComponent<nameOfClassattachedtoHandler>().randID;`

Comment: @outlaw-lemur His `DecideID` function is ugly and buggy. It worth explaining how to fix it, providing that you have decided to answer the question.

Comment: @SergeyKrusch Check edits... I hadn't noticed that trick with the float;)

Comment: @JackMiller Check my edits... It explains a better way to do things, with different options to choose from for implementation

Comment: @outlaw-lemur Yep :) Something like this